SwiftUI: Does anyone know why my .onDrag or .onDrop modifiers are not getting invoked?
Below are the two Views that should matter for this question.  I'm just trying to drag and drop a Meal from one place in a List to another (same List).  The idea is to let the user adjust the time of the specific Meal on their Meal Plan.  I feel like I have tried just about everything, but the .onDrop modifier is not getting called.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! I would love to know what's preventing this from working.
Here is a picture of what the animation looks like when I begin dragging:

import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct CalendarDayListView2: View {
    
    @State var viewModel: CalendarDayListViewModel2
    @Binding var date: Date
    @Binding var meals: [Meal]
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    
    @State private var scrollToMeal: Meal?
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    @State private var timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current

    var plusButtonAction: ((Date) -> Void)?
    var xButtonAction: ((Meal) -> Void)?
    var menuButtonAction: ((Meal) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                ForEach(hoursOfDay, id: \.self) { hour in
                    if let meal = mealForHour(hour) {
                        CalendarListItemView(
                            meal: meal,
                            date: hour,
                            mode: viewModel.mode,
                            plusButtonAction: { addMealDate in
                                // Handle plus button action
                                self.plusButtonAction?(addMealDate)
                            },
                            xButtonAction: { meal in
                                // Handle x button action
                                self.xButtonAction?(meal)
                            }, menuButtonAction: { meal in
                                self.menuButtonAction?(meal)
                            }
                        )
                        .id(meal.id)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                            Button(role: .destructive) {
                                deleteMeal(meal)
                            } label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                        .onDrag {
                            NSItemProvider(object: meal.id as NSString)
                        }
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text.identifier], delegate: CalendarDropDelegate(meals: $meals, date: hour))

                    } else {
                        CalendarListItemView(
                            meal: nil,
                            date: hour,
                            mode: viewModel.mode,
                            plusButtonAction: { addMealDate in
                                // Handle plus button action
                                self.plusButtonAction?(addMealDate)
                            },
                            xButtonAction: { meal in
                                // Handle x button action
                                self.xButtonAction?(meal)
                            }, menuButtonAction: { meal in
                                self.menuButtonAction?(meal)
                            }
                        )
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.plainText.identifier], delegate: CalendarDropDelegate(meals: $meals, date: hour))

                    }
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                
                // Add extra padding for iPhone SE
                if sizeCategory == .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 200)
                }
                else {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 450)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 700)
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .onChange(of: self.meals) {
                
                scrollToMeal = self.meals.first
            }
            .onChange(of: scrollToMeal) {
                if let meal = scrollToMeal {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(meal.id, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: self.date) { oldValue, newValue in
                
                // Meal Sharing mode
                scrollToMeal = mealsForSelectedDate.first
            }
            .onChange(of: self.isLoading) { oldValue, newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        scrollToMeal = mealsForSelectedDate.first
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func deleteMeal(_ meal: Meal) {
        if let index = meals.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == meal.id }) {
            meals.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    private func dateForHour(_ hour: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hour, to: startOfDay)!
    }
    
    private var hoursOfDay: [Date] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var calendarWithTimeZone = calendar
        calendarWithTimeZone.timeZone = timeZone
        let startOfDay = calendarWithTimeZone.startOfDay(for: date)
        return (0..<24).map { hour in
            calendarWithTimeZone.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hour, to: startOfDay)!
        }
    }
    
    private var mealsForSelectedDate: [Meal] {
        self.meals.filter { meal in
            guard let plannedAt = meal.plannedAt else { return false }
            return Calendar.current.isDate(plannedAt, inSameDayAs: date)
        }
    }
    
    private func mealForHour(_ hour: Date) -> Meal? {
        mealsForSelectedDate.first { meal in
            guard var plannedAt = meal.plannedAt else { return false }
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            var calendarWithTimeZone = calendar
            calendarWithTimeZone.timeZone = timeZone
            
            // Convert plannedAt to the current timezone
            plannedAt = plannedAt.convertToTimeZone(timeZone)
            
            return calendarWithTimeZone.isDate(plannedAt, equalTo: hour, toGranularity: .hour)
        }
    }
}

struct CalendarDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var meals: [Meal]
    let date: Date

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let itemProvider = info.itemProviders(for: [.text]).first else { return false }

        itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSString.self) { (id, error) in
            if let id = id as? String,
               let index = meals.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    var updatedMeal = meals[index]
                    print("performDrop: UpdatedMeal date: \(date)")
                    updatedMeal.plannedAt = date
                    meals[index] = updatedMeal
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}


// CalendarListItemView.swift
struct CalendarListItemView: View {
    
    var meal: Meal?
    var date: Date
    var mode: CalendarViewMode
    @State var isSelected: Bool = false
    
    var plusButtonAction: ((Date) -> Void)?
    var xButtonAction: ((Meal) -> Void)?
    var menuButtonAction: ((Meal) -> Void)?
    
    var foodImageNotDisplayed = false
    
    var hourString: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        // Set the locale to ensure AM/PM works correctly in all locales
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        // Set the desired format
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh"
        
        // Return the formatted date string
        return formatter.string(from: self.date)
    }
    
    var meridianString: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        // Set the locale to ensure AM/PM works correctly in all locales
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        // Set the desired format
        formatter.dateFormat = "a"
        
        // Return the formatted date string
        return formatter.string(from: self.date)
    }
            
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black.opacity(0.03))
                    .frame(width: 75, height: self.meal == nil ? 33.0 : 75.0 )
                HStack {
                    Text(hourString)
                        .font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text(meridianString)
                        .font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.5))
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            
            if meal != nil {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    foodImage()
                    
                    VStack {
                        if let meal = meal {
                            
                            Text(meal.title)
                                .font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: 15))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            if let calories = meal?.calories {
                                Text("\(calories.formatDouble()) cals")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: 13))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.54, green: 0.72, blue: 0.13))
                            }

                            if let readyInMinutes = meal?.readyInMinutes {
                                Text("• \(readyInMinutes) minutes")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: 13))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.54, green: 0.72, blue: 0.13))
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            if let meal = meal {
                Button(action: {
                    if self.mode == .mealSharing {
                        self.menuButtonAction?(meal)
                    }
                    else {
                        xButtonAction?(meal)
                    }
                }, label: {
                    if self.mode == .mealSharing {
                        Image("menu_button")
                    }
                    else {
                        Image("x_button")
                    }
                })
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            // No meal for time slot
            else {
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.isSelected.toggle()
                    if self.mode == .timeSlot {
                        self.plusButtonAction?(date)
                    }
                    
                }, label: {
                    if self.mode == .timeSlot && self.isSelected {
                        Image("green_checkmark")
                    }
                    else if self.mode == .mealSharing {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    else {
                        Image("plus_button")
                    }
                })
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: self.meal == nil ? 50.0 : 75.0)
    }
        
    @ViewBuilder
    func foodImage() -> some View {
        if let imageUrl = meal?.image, let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
                if let image = phase.image {
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                } else if phase.error != nil {
                    Image("placeholder_food_image")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .clipped()
                } else {
                    Image("placeholder_food_image")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        } else {
            Image("placeholder_food_image")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}

I tried the .onMove modifier and that did not work as well.  I tried multiple different UTTypes for the .onDrop and that did not work.  The crazy thing is I even tested making the ForEach simply iterate and display Text views of the hour and it still would not let me drop them.

This needs a [mre]

That first @State is missing its initial value. Your text formatting is leaking formatter objects.

You don't have to use onDrag/onDrop for reordering items in List.
Here is an simplified example of how you can achieve that:
List(selection: $selected) {
    ForEach($items, id: \.id) { item in
        ItemView(item)
            .tag(item.id.wrappedValue)
    }
    .onMove { indices, newOffset in
        items.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
    }
}


Great example, it was the ".tag" that i was missing.  Once I added it, everything started working.
